# TIBCO Spotfire expressions : How to rename a group of nest columns into new names

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

I have Bar chart with values colored by 2 different filters.
What I need is to rename each combination of the 2 filters into just one name.

i tried to write it with CASE expression but with no luck.

below screenshot, shows what is required.

Any ideas ?

Screenshot sample : [Motor Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi6IC.png)

Comment: Please post your Case statement attempts. It'll make it easier to help as a case statement should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you case expression not work?

Something like that should work:

```
<CASE [COLUMN] WHEN "VALUE1" then "Category A" WHEN "VALUE2" then "Category B" ELSE "Category C" END>
```

But in your situation I would do

```
<if([column 2] in ('SALA','SUPP'),'Motor category A','Motor category B')>
```

Add this expression here (right click > custom expression) :
[image]

Comment: Thanks Mickael , i tried to do so but it keeps saying error .

Comment: Where should i place this expression , im sorry im new to Spotfire

Comment: Right click on the column used for the color and select "Custom Expression".

Comment: Thanks for your help. its done but why it requires that all columns must be present , when i write the expression i have to "NEST" the columns on the case which does not make the output summarized to the cases i already wrote.

Comment: For a more precise answer, you'll have to share more details on your visualisation, like the type of viz and the axes you use.

Comment: Im using Bar chart , and color by the expression , but instead of just dividing each bar with motor type it also has the other two layers LIKE : Motor Type A >> Book >> SALA. i just want to color by the Motor Type